# how to change custom font for the list items

Tags: android

How to change the font of the ListView items? Here I want to change the font to helvetica regular font. My TextView is assigned to the string variable. Please help me. Thank you in advance.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(newandroid.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick (AdapterView < ? > arg0, View view,int arg2, long arg3){

        String countryname = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.countryname)).getText().toString();//this is the textview id assigned to the string variable//
        String coutrylist = "Algeria:DZ:213:49,Adrar;27,Ain Defla;43,Ain Temouchent"// these are the some of the list items in the list view//
        String split[] = coutrylist.split("\\$");
        // creating new HashMap
        String cid = "";
        String ccode = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            if (split[i].startsWith(countryname)) {
                String split3[] = split[i].split("\\:");
                cid = split3[2];
                ccode = split3[1];
            }
        }
        // On selecting single track get song information
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Npanxx.class);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "seleceted : " + countryname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        i.putExtra("country", countryname);
        i.putExtra("code", ccode);
        i.putExtra("id", cid);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you are using studio. Paste your font in src/main/assets/fonts/helveticaregular.ttf. And use this code to set the typface.

```
 Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/helveticaregular.ttf");
            txtView.setTypeface(myTypeface);
```

But I think you put here the wrong part of code. Probably you want this in your listview adapter.

**Edit**

You'll need to override the SimpleAdapter's getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) method and cast the result to a TextView.

From there, setting a typeface works as usual.

Snippet, to be placed inside an (anonymous) extension of SimpleAdapter:

```
Typeface mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/helveticaregular.ttf"); // only needs to be initialised once.

@Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    TextView countryname = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.countryname));
    countryname.setTypeface(mTypeface);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: i assigned my textview id to variable how to set typface to that country name

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
   // dismiss the dialog after getting all albums
   pDialog.dismiss();
   // updating UI from Background Thread
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
     /**
      * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
      * */
     ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
       CoutryList.this, albumsList,
       R.layout.country_list_item2, new String[] { TAG_NAME,TAG_ID}, new int[] {
         R.id.countryname,R.id.countryflag});
     
     // updating listview
     setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
   });

  }

Answer (score 0):

First download the .ttf file of the font you need (helvetica.ttf). Place it in the assets folder(Inside assest folder create new folder named "fonts" and place it inside it). Now use following piece of code below TextView initialization.

```
Typeface myFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/helvetica.ttf"); 
countryname.setTypeface(myFont);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom adapter for listview in custom adapter through findViewById method of View and the setTypeface method of TextView like below!

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)

{

View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent); 

 TextView countryname = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.countryname));                              

 //put some custom font in your assets directory 
 countryname.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset
    (view.getContext().getAssets(),"yourfonttype.otf"));// you can also use   
                                                        your context instead 
                                                        of view.getContext() 
                                                        that was asign from 
                                                         activity 

return view;
}
```